# How do I find $E(E(X^2|Y))$?

Tags: probability

Currently my homework questions have a list of questions. We are required to find the probability density function. 
I know, $E(X|Y)$, $E(E(X|Y))$, I can't figure out the correlation between any of those and $E(E(X^2|Y))$?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Please be more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

If you have calculated $E_{X|Y}(X|Y)$ then you should be able to calculate $E_Y\left(E_{X^2|Y}(X|Y)\right)$ the same way. First calculate $E_{X|Y}(X^2|Y)$ the same way you calculated $E_{X|Y}(X|Y)$, just substituting $x^2$ for $x$, and then take the expectation of that outcome over $Y$.

A possible shortcut relates to the [Law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation) which is:
$$
\large E(X) = E_Y\left(E_{X|Y}(X|Y)\right)
$$
which in English means that if you have a conditional expectation of $X$ given $Y$, and then you take the expectation of **that** value over all $Y$, you end up with the overall expectation of $X$.

So if you are able to calculate $E(X^2)$ without any conditioning that result is equivalent to $ E_Y\left(E_{X|Y}(X^2|Y)\right)$.